# What is a good way to exchange data between ReactJs (not react native) webview and android native

Tags: android, reactjs, android-webview

Im loading page from Reactjs into webview .
Im fetching some data in async (current location) and want to send it to react component.
I need to communicate between android native and **ReactJs** component to update store .